# RDF4j v3.0.0 Export graph without inferred triples in it

Tags: rdf4j

in version 3.0.0, since inferred triples are added into an actual graph (not into the default as before), is it somehow possible to  export/fetch an actual graph without the inferred triples? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

### 1. Via the Java API

You can retrieve the statements from named graph `http://example.org/graph1` in several ways. Showing two alternatives here:

```java
 IRI graph1 = valueFactory.createIRI("http://example.org/graph1");

 try(RepositoryConnection conn = repository.getConnection()) {

     // option 1: getStatements of everything in a named graph, setting
     // includeInferred to false
     RepositoryResult<Statement> result = conn.getStatement(null, null, null, false, graph1);

    // option 2: using export with an RDFHandler (export never includes inferred triples)
    RDFHandler collector = new StatementCollector(); 
    conn.export(graph1, collector);
 }
```

### 2. Via the RDF4J Workbench

The simplest way to do this in the workbench is to use a SPARQL CONSTRUCT query:

```
construct from <http://example.org/graph1> where { ?s ?p ?o }
```

Make sure that the "include inferred statements" option is unchecked before hitting 'Execute'. Then on the query result screen, pick your preferred download format, and hit 'Download'.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I use query=construct from <http://example.org/graph1> where { ?s ?p ?o } with infer=false over RDF4j Rest Api.